# Not able to access other jsp pages other then index.jsp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using eclipse IDE and trying to run a simple HelloWorld Spring MVC app. While web/index.jsp doesn't have an issue, I cannot get the /WEB-INF/views/final.jsp to display correctly (I'm using http://localhost:8080/springmvc/home ). I keep getting (404-not found) error.

Below is my setup. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->  
<dependency>    
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>    
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>    
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>    
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <!-- Configure dispatcher servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">  
  
    <!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->  
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="springmvc.controller"/> 
 
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>     
    
 </bean>

 </beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
package springmvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller

public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value ="/home")
    public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("This is home URL");
        return "final";
    }
    
    
}
```

index.jsp

```
<html>  
<body>  
<a href="home">Click here...</a>  
</body>  
</html>
```

final.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is home Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Project Structure is as below

[image]

Comment: Why put `springmvc` in between `http://localhost:8080/springmvc/home` url?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhane  http://localhost:8080/springmvc/ is default url which gets open when I run application and that page is working fine. gets error when add /home

Comment: remove `springmvc` from url and try

Comment: Tried not working..

Comment: add dependency in your question

Comment: dependency added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241304/discussion-between-shubham-boora-and-faeemazaz-bhanej).

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason for this error I was executing this code on tomcat version 10, from  version 10 package (javax) are replaced with jakarta so dispatcherServlet was not able to detect javax package and was giving this error. I downgraded my tomcat version to 9 and it worked fine another solution could be to use packages which support jakarta insted of javax.